# Java alternatives to GradientPaint / GradientPaint is slow

Tags: java

Are there alternatives to using GradientPaint in Java?

Basically at this moment my code is acceptably fast when I fill all rectangles in my application with a solid color.

However as soon as I start to use a GradientPaint, then the performance drops by 1 second for an action.

An action for example is: Clicking on an image, and then the image pops up in big.

I like to keep the look of the GradientPaint as a normal fill just looks horrible... But I do not want to lose the performance. Are there any alternatives to GradientPaint?

I hope my question is not too vague, but it just seems that GradientPaint is too slow. I have tried to manually implement a GradientPaint and the performance is close to the Java implementation, so could be an indication that GradientPaint simply cannot be done more efficiently.

The code that uses GradientPaint:

```
private void drawRectangle(final Graphics2D g2d, int width, int height, int x, int y, final int borderSize, final Color color) {        
    g2d.setColor(color);
    g2d.fillRect(x, y, width, height);

    //account for border distance
    x += borderSize;
    y += borderSize;
    width -= 2 * borderSize;
    height -= 2 * borderSize;

    int mx = (int)Math.round(x + (width / 2));
    int my = (int)Math.round(y + (height / 2));   

    Color colorEdge = alphaColor(color, 192);
    Color colorInside = alphaColor(color, 128);

    Composite oldComposite = g2d.getComposite();

    g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcIn);
    g2d.setColor(color);
    GradientPaint paintQ1 = new GradientPaint(x, y, colorEdge, mx, my, colorInside);
    g2d.setPaint(paintQ1);
    g2d.fillRect(x, y, mx - x, my - y);

    GradientPaint paintQ2 = new GradientPaint(x + width - 1, y, colorEdge, mx, my, colorInside);
    g2d.setPaint(paintQ2);
    g2d.fillRect(mx, y, mx - x, my - y);

    GradientPaint paintQ3 = new GradientPaint(x, y + height - 1, colorEdge, mx, my, colorInside);
    g2d.setPaint(paintQ3);
    g2d.fillRect(x, my, mx - x, my - y);

    GradientPaint paintQ4 = new GradientPaint(x + width - 1, y + height - 1, colorEdge, mx, my, colorInside);
    g2d.setPaint(paintQ4);
    g2d.fillRect(mx, my, mx - x, my - y);
    g2d.setComposite(oldComposite);
}

private Color alphaColor(final Color c1, final int alpha) {
    return new Color(c1.getRed(), c1.getGreen(), c1.getBlue(), alpha);
}
```

It is called like just 3 times per image covering a total area of approximately two times 500 by 700 pixels.

Regards.

Comment: Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) when you ask a question. You have been asked for a SSCCE in other questions as well!

Comment: If I would be trying to put a SSCCE together for this problem then it would either not contain enough information or it would not agree with the term SSCCE anymore... Trust me, if I could've put this in an SSCCE then I would have, because I would like to know the answer aswell.

Comment: Check out this [Troubleshooting guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/java2d.html#gdpio) for Java 2D rendering and performance issues. There is also a discussion about GradientPaint performance at http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php/topic,7576. , but it is a bit dated.

Answer (score 1):

Answering 6 years late, but for anyone who finds it:

In general, the way Java Paint instances work is that they allocate very large rasters (int or byte arrays) behind the scenes, and these then get discarded fairly quickly and recreated the next time you paint.  It's compounded somewhat by the fact that Java2D is oriented around pushing pixels, and that is not how modern graphics pipelines work.

You can work around this *within some limitations*:  If you are just doing horizontal or vertical gradients, it can be much more performant to paint the gradient *once* into a screen-compatible BufferedImage (you can do a fairly small image and tile it vertically or horizontally);  for my needs, performance was improved around 20x.  Here's a project that uses this approach which is usable as a library:  https://github.com/timboudreau/visual-library-tabcontrol/tree/master/colors/src/main/java/com/mastfrog/colors

Of course, if you're doing complex RadialGradientPaints, that's not going to be tilable;  it *might* be possible to handle tiling at arbitrary angles, but it's non-trivial - set a transform on the graphics so tiling goes at the desired angle, and transform all of the shapes so they will appear oriented normally.